# Open excel using java and detect when its closed

Tags: java, excel

I am looking to open an excel spreadsheet from java and be notified back (or detect) when its closed

I know how to open it (which basically executes the win command )

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\\\"prog file\"\\090422.xls");
```

However, is there way I can know when the excel is closed?

Thanks

Comment: [Process#waitFor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor())

Comment: Can you ellaborate a bit more?

Comment: Runtime.exec returns a Process. You can use waitFor to wait until the process exists...

Comment: perfect, have as an answer and i will acept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Process#waitFor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29), each will wait until the process terminates before returning.

`Runtime.exec` will return a refernce to `Process`, so make sure you are assigning it to a variable

Comment: Btw the problem is that  you open 2 spreadsheet then it is once instance opening them and no way of knowing when each is  terminated

Comment: Knowing when a spread sheet is opened or closed its possible, as it's done within the context of the application (the process)

Comment: Check my other question please for better description of the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278082/from-java-how-to-be-notified-when-excel-spreadsheet-is-closed-given-multi-sprea